# How to add coastline detection (for smoother transitions between the water and the coast) using blender cycles material nodes?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

How to add coastline detection (for smoother transitions between the water and the coast) using blender cycles material nodes?

My intention is to do something like this water shader made for the Martinsh from BA.

http://www.blendernation.com/2013/06/22/waterunderwater-sky-shader/

But insteed of a real time shader, I wish a blender cycles shader!

I managed to recreate all major aspects... volumetrics, caustics... but I can't find a way to do the smooth transitions between the water and the coastline!

Someone have a hint?

Comment: I think dynamic paint is what you are looking for.

Comment: besides dynamic paint... Maybe something with the normal or geometry nodes... some trick to run in the shader itself, if you know what I mean...

Comment: This just isn't possible using only material nodes currently, without drivers you only have information about the object using the material (even then, I don't think you have enough information). It might be possible with OSL, but I don't know enough about it.. This seems right up the alley for dynamic paint, why not use it?

Comment: thanks for the explanation man! For some reason I was thinking that it was possible to do with material nodes, like it is possible in game engines like UDK or Unity... I'll try with the dynamic paint then!

Comment: Keep looking, there is a tutorial on this very thing that I saw last fall but I've forgotten the relevant details to find it right away.  I'm just saying this so you have some extra motivation to keep searching since I know it's out there somewhere close.

Comment: @MarcClintDion Thanks for the hint mate! I'll search for it! ;)